# PHP Regular Expression [accept selected characters only]

Tags: php, regex, string, validation, preg-match

I want to accept a list of character as input from the user and reject the rest. I can accept a formatted string or find if a character/string is missing.
But how I can accept only a set of character while reject all other characters. I would like to use preg_match to do this.

e.g. Allowable characters are: a..z, A..Z, -, ’ ‘
User must able to enter those character in any order. But they must not allowed to use other than those characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a negated character class: [^A-Za-z-\w]

This will only match if the user enters something OTHER than what is in that character class.

```
if (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z-\w]/', $input)) { /* invalid charcter entered */ }
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you please explain the \w

Comment: It's for standard word characters. I'm using it sort of redundantly. I believe it matches [A-Za-z0-9_] (all letters, numbers, and underscore) if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

[a-zA-Z-\w]

[] brackets are used to group characters and behave like a single character. so you can also do stuff like [...]+ and so on
also a-z, A-Z, 0-9 define ranges so you don't have to write the whole alphabet

Comment: oh and you could also use \s to match white space characters (space, tab, newline and so on)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression: `^[a-zA-Z -]+$`.

The `^` matches the beginning of the string, which prevents it from matching the middle of the string `123abc`.  The `$` similarly matches the end of the string, preventing it from matching the middle of `abc123`.
The brackets match every character inside of them; `a-z` means every character between `a` and `z`.  To match the `-` character itself, put it at the end.  (`[19-]` matches a `1`, a `9`, or a `-`; `[1-9]` matches every character between `1` and `9`, and does not match `-`).
The `+` tells it to match one or more of the thing before it.  You can replace the `+` with a `*`, which means 0 or more, if you also want to match an empty string.

For more information, see [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html).

Comment: @Matt: I'm well aware of that.  Think twice before downvoting.

Comment: @SLaks
Informative, though not exactly the answer. +1 :)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You would be looking at a negated `^` character class `[]` that stipulates your allowed characters, then test for matches.

```
$pattern = '/[^A-Za-z\- ]/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $string_of_input)){
   //return a fail
}

//Matt beat me too it...
```